# Inconsistent Layout in iPhone 5/5s & iPhone 6/6p

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This problem look odd to me, when I tried to run it on iPhone 5/5s simulator. It works perfectly no doubt. But when I tried it in iPhone 6/6p, there are some extra trailing spacing.

My **Master View** look like below.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/reml045y1b069g9/Screenshot%202015-07-07%2013.00.55.png?dl=0

The **Master View** embedded with a Navigation Controller and the **Container View (Grey Color View)** is the subview of the **Master View**. It is use for add in subview from another view controller.

Also, the constraints for the **Container View (Grey Color View)** look like below.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x27f3u8lniwmnoa/Screenshot%202015-07-07%2013.03.22.png?dl=0

It means that it will keep to top subview & bottom, left & right superview. And it is working fine in any of the screen so far.

The **Subview's View Controller** look like below.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9ytnmv38jz90ii/Screenshot%202015-07-07%2013.06.00.png?dl=0

A standalone **View Controller** with only a **Table View** inside.

The **Table View** constraints look like below.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z57sl9djk4t22qa/Screenshot%202015-07-07%2013.07.08.png?dl=0

It means that it will keep to top, bottom, left & right superview.

---

I've tried to debug by using iPhone 6  to see whether is the **Container View (Grey Color View)** or the **Subview's View Controller** giving problems.

**Experiment 1:**

Put a label by align vertically with trailing space. The outcome working perfectly.

**Storyboard View**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2oabl4oxcyx6vp/Screenshot%202015-07-07%2013.12.38.png?dl=0

**Simulator View**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d3rldx0xod55oaw/Screenshot%202015-07-07%2013.12.11.png?dl=0

**Experiment 2:**

Modify **Table View Trailing Space Constant Value** from 0 to 100 to see the spacing. But the outcome for the Trailing Space seems like only have 40 - 50.

**Storyboard View**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/99e8ct1tp07cew1/Screenshot%202015-07-07%2013.15.36.png?dl=0

**Simulator View**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/34h9ugcbvbu3v2e/Screenshot%202015-07-07%2013.17.47.png?dl=0

---

Here is my codes that how I add the **Subview View Controller's View** into the **Container View (Grey Color View)**.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard    = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
LocalPhotoAlbumVC *vc       = (LocalPhotoAlbumVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LocalPhotoAlbumVC"];
vc.mDelegate                = (id)self;

[self addChildViewController:vc];
[self.containerView addSubview:vc.view];
[vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```